# Error while adding Azure credentials on Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to add the Azure credentials (Microsoft Azure Service Principal) on jenkins server under

Credentials -> System -> Global Credentials.

Copied the subscription ID from my App service and added all the necessary information. When I click **Verify Service Principal**, I am getting **The subscription id is not valid** error.

I am pretty sure the subscription Id is correct. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Some screenshots and links to documentation you are following would be helpful.

Comment: Your sp have `Owner` role on your subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though i get that error i was able to save the settings and connect to Azure. It is definitely weird.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced similar issue and the solution is adding required permissions to the service principal which we are using to authenticate.
With out any permissions on subscription it cannot validate.

Comment: Great, that is correct. Thank you. Do you know what is the minimal permission the service principal must have, or maybe any is enough.

Comment: minimal/any would be enough, worked to me like that

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give the service principal access to your subscription by assigning a role to it. To assign a role to the service principal, go to the subscription level > access control (IAM) > add role assignment.

For Jenkins, I actually assign an owner or a contributor role to it. But you can choose the whatever role is appropriate for your use case. You can find more details about service principals [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar error and I resolved it by using the **subscription ID** of the **resource group** where I created a **Service Principal**
[image: Resource Group subscription ID]